# react-pdf off track on render

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

{Array.from(new Array(numPages), (el, index) => (
<Page key={`page_${index + 1}`} pageNumber={index + 1} />
))}

I believe this array is throwing the pdf off track for the first two pages or if anyone else has encountered this please help.

***pdf alignment off for page 1-2***
[image: pdf alignment off for page 1-2]

***pdf alignment every page after 2***
[image: pdf alignment every page after 2]

https://codesandbox.io/s/5d003

I am working with the "all-page" part of this repo from app.js. I am creating a pdf page for my sample .pdf reports to live on my website. When it renders it throws the second and third pages down three times the padding set and gets back on track for pages 3-52 no problem. Please look at pics.